# Two-port circuit with input/output duality

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, terminology

Suppose I have a circuit with two ports. One port is considered the input, and the second port is considered the output.

Assume it's described via

$$V_{out} = \frac{V_{in}}{2}$$

Now assume there's no voltage applied to the input terminals.

Supply the output port with  5 V. If I measure the terminals of the input port, will I see 10 V?

In general, the answer is no, of course, as a voltage divider will show.

What do you call circuits that do satisfy the behavior where you measure 10 V at the input port given a supplied 5 V source at the output port? I'm asking for a general term, but using an example to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: which behavior? .... you talked about two

Comment: Hmmm... Reversable?  Bidirectional? Ambivalent?  I move that we all use "Ambivalent voltage converter" from now on.  Seriously though probably bidirectional.

Comment: @KH I like that term. It's intuitive, and simple. If you answer with this same comment, I'll accept it.

Comment: We'll wait a while to see if one of the engineers pops in, as they could comment with greater certainty than I and there may be an existing accepted term.

Comment: You got it! I'm just trying to avoid one of those cases where a question has a good answer in the comments but never becomes an actual "answer" for years and years.

Comment: In case of AC, you'd call it a transformator

Comment: @Humpawumpa I guess you mean 'transformer'.

Comment: Of course, sorry...

Comment: A synchronous CCM buck converter can be bi-directional: it can decrease the input voltage to \$V_{out}=DV_{in}\$ while when working in reverse mode, it can boost the output port to \$V_{in}=V_{out}\frac{1}{1-D}\$ if you consider the buck input port now as an output. This is sometimes an unwanted effect in sync buck converters during the turn-off sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In the specific case where \$V_\text{out}\$ and \$V_\text{in}\$ take on only two possible levels, the device is known as a [*bidirectional (logic) level translator/converter/shifter.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_shifter)
- In the specific case where \$V_\text{out} = V_\text{in}\$, it is of course a wire or transmission line.
- In the specific case where the device can be switched between \$V_\text{out} = V_\text{in}\$ and no connection, it is a switch — or, if implemented in semiconductors rather than mechanically, specifically an [*analog switch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogue_switch) or [transmission gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate).

I do not expect there is a *formal term* for the general case of this behavior because it's not a realistic "found" behavior in a circuit except in special cases that are best considered on their own. That said, “bidirectional” would be a reasonable word to use — just don't expect it to automatically imply everything you've described here.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... Reversible? Invertible? Bidirectional? Ambivalent? 
I move that we all use "Ambivalent voltage converter" from now on. Seriously though probably bidirectional.